# Comparing an input string with a string that has a integer variable in C?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I'm trying to compare an input of characters with a string that can be of the format "!x" where x is any integer.

What's the easiest way to do this? I tried

```
int result = strcmp(input,"!%d");
```

which did not work.

Comment: Why did you expect it to work?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, what is the content of `input`?

Comment: @AlanAu How can I catch when the second character is a char and not an int?

Comment: @sc1892353 All characters are characters.

Comment: Can you please clarify your intent?

Comment: @sc1892353 Your question doesn't have that as a requirement. Put all your requirements in the question if you want a full answer. It's too unclear at the moment. In particular, post sample input and what you are actually trying to compare with.

Comment: @sc1892353 as Alan Au said, it's not clear what you want to compare.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
int is_bang_num(const char *s) {
    if (*s != '!') {
        return 0;
    }
    size_t n = strspn(s + 1, "0123456789");
    return n > 0 && s[1 + n] == '\0';
}
```

This verifies that the first character is `!`, that it is followed by more characters, and that all of those following characters are digits.

Comment: I do think that this is what the OP wants. But this code is unecessarily unsafe.

Comment: @iharob How is it unsafe?

Comment: @iharob This function takes a string. `NULL` is not a string. You can't guard against a caller passing non-strings. `*s == '\0'` is fine. What's unsafe about that?

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't think of that. Sorry :) I still like to check against `NULL`, any good reason to not do that?

Comment: @iharob None of the string functions in the standard library check for `NULL`. And all you could do in that situation is hide a bug in the caller (or call `abort()`, but in that case why not simply crash?).

Comment: Not necessarily crash, and you sould give a warning like *WARNING: There is a bug in your code.* You know that the program can continue without crashing if `s == NULL`, don't you? Dereferencing a `NULL` poitner is *Undefined Behavior* so you can't predict the outcome. And if you let the program continue after that, you can corrupt data in the program, thus potentially corrupting data on the permanent storage like a database. It has happened to me in the past and since then, I became extremely paranoic about this. Also, don't you check for `NULL` before calling one of the `str`* functions?

Comment: Some programmers do things like `char *string = malloc(length + 1); strcpy(string, something);`. This is potentially dereferencing a `NULL` pointer too. Checking for `NULL` was bad because computers were slow and it seemed like a waste of cpu cycles. But undefined behavior is your enemy, you should avoid it as much as possible. It's just my opinion though.

Comment: OP's  coding code is "Comparing an input string with a string ...".  `NULL` is not a string so no requirement to check if `s==NULL`.  We _could_ add a check for `NULL`, could add a check to see if the integer is in an `int` range, all sort of unrequested checks.  Rather than those side issues: what about code goal issues of "x is any integer." like "-123", `+0xABC"?  These are not address here.

Comment: @chux I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You see, `scanf()` family of functions return a value indicating how many parameters where converted.

Even books usually ignore this value and it leads programmers to ignore that it does return a value. One of the consequences of this is *Undefined Behavior* when the `scanf()` function failed and the value was not initialized, not before calling `scanf()` and since it has failed not by `scanf()` either.

You can use this value returned by `sscanf()` to check for success, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    const char *string;
    int value;
    int result;
    string = "!12345";
    result = sscanf(string, "!%d", &value);
    if (result == 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "the value was: %d\n", value);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "the string did not match the pattern\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, if one parameter was successfuly scanned it means that the string matched pattern, otherwise it didn't.

With this approach you also extract the integral value, but you should be careful because `scanf()`'s are not meant for regular expressions, this would work in very simple situations.

Comment: If by "fail" you mean parse it successfully, then yes. `scanf` `%d` skips leading whitespace.

Comment: @melpomene Correct, I wasn't thinking clearly last night because I was very tired.

Answer (score 0):

Since the stirng must begin with a ! and follow with an integer, use a qualified `strtol()` which allows a leading sign character. As OP did not specify the range of the integer, let us allow any range.

```
int is_sc_num(const char *str) {
  if (*str != '!') return 0;
  str++;

  // Insure no spaces- something strtol() allows.
  if (isspace((unsigned char) *str) return 0;

  char *endptr;
  // errno = 0;

  // By using base 0, input like "0xABC" allowed
  strtol(str, &endptr, 0);

  // no check for errno as code allows any range
  // if (errno == ERANGE) return 0

  if (str == endptr) return 0;  // no digits
  if (*endptr) return 0; // Extra character at the end
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to test that a string matches a format of an exclamation point and then some series of numbers, this regex: "!\d+" will match that. That won't catch if the first number is a zero, which is invalid. This will: "![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]\d*".